# Show specific options using radio buttons?

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been answered a few times and i found the answer as well. However the code doesn't seem to work the website I am trying to make. It is a static page and should work without internet. I think I am missing to define some function. please help!

```html
<form>
<input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio1">Option1</input> 
<input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio2">Option2</input>
<input id="id_radio3" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio3">Option3</input>
<input id="id_radio4" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio4">Option4</input>
<br>    
<div id="ar_1" style="display:none;">
<p>info for option1</p>
</div>
<div id="ar_2" style="display:none;">
<p>info for option2</p>
</div>
<div id="ar_3" style="display:none;">
<p>info for option3</p>
</div>
<div id="ar_4" style="display:none;">
<p>info for option4</p>
</div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#id_radio1').click(function () {
        $('#ar_1').show('fast');
        $('#ar_2').hide('fast');        
        $('#ar_3').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_4').hide('fast');
    });
    $('#id_radio2').click(function () {
        $('#ar_1').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_2').show('fast');
        $('#ar_3').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_4').hide('fast');
    });
     $('#id_radio3').click(function () {
        $('#ar_1').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_2').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_3').show('fast');
        $('#ar_4').hide('fast');
    })
     $('#id_radio4').click(function () {
        $('#ar_1').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_2').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_3').hide('fast');
        $('#ar_4').show('fast');
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: This might sound obvious, but is jQuery loaded in your page?

Comment: Please spellcheck your post title. Also, please write in standard international English. This means capitalizing the first word of a sentence, and ending sentences with a full stop (period). Also capitalizing the word "I". Please fix this, thanks.

Comment: You need to tell us what doesn't work, and what the results are of your attempts to debug it, such as walking through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo, Thanks for the feedback. I am a newbie in this field. I hope i will be able to match your standards in the coming months. :)

Comment: They're not my standards, they're standards for the site. Why cannot you not describe what is not working?

Comment: Hi @Simon Belanger, jQuery was not loaded in the page. the solution to the same by Poiz worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Its not that i cannot describe what is not working, however i missed on that. The problem has been resolved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Code, you seem to be using JQuery Library. However, you have no import for that anywhere in your Code. For you code to thus work; you'd either have to include a Local Copy of JQuery (since you don't have Internet Access) or just load it from Hosted Servers (if you have Internet Access). [Quick-Test it Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5p4tmnk2/).

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<!-- LOCAL JQUERY INCLUDED IN SCRIPT TAG FIRST -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- OR PULLED FROM HOSTED CDN: DELETE THIS OPTION IF YOU HAVE NO INTERNET ACCESS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(evt){
            $('#id_radio1').click(function () {
                $('#ar_1').show('fast');
                $('#ar_2').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_3').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_4').hide('fast');
            });

            $('#id_radio2').click(function () {
                $('#ar_1').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_2').show('fast');
                $('#ar_3').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_4').hide('fast');
            });

            $('#id_radio3').click(function () {
                $('#ar_1').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_2').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_3').show('fast');
                $('#ar_4').hide('fast');
            });

            $('#id_radio4').click(function () {
                $('#ar_1').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_2').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_3').hide('fast');
                $('#ar_4').show('fast');
            })

        });
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <form>
        <input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio1">Option1</input>
        <input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio2">Option2</input>
        <input id="id_radio3" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio3">Option3</input>
        <input id="id_radio4" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio4">Option4</input>
        <br>
        <div id="ar_1" style="display:none;">
            <p>info for option1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ar_2" style="display:none;">
            <p>info for option2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ar_3" style="display:none;">
            <p>info for option3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="ar_4" style="display:none;">
            <p>info for option4</p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: the solution related to jQuery import worked. Thank you for the help!